# Safe way to convert array dimensions in Rust

Tags: arrays, rust

I have program that has a large lookup table in it. To save time, rather than generating the appropriate values every time the program runs, I simply load it from a file.

When I read the values from a file buffer, I get an array of `u8`'s. My lookup table is a two dimensional array of `u8`'s. Right now I'm using `std::mem::transmute` to convert from this one dimensional array to the two dimensional array. However, I've noticed that the community generally frowns on the use of `std::mem::transmute` e.g.

> transmute is incredibly unsafe. There are a vast number of ways to cause undefined behavior with this function. transmute should be the absolute last resort.
>
> https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.transmute.html

Currently, this is the only efficient way I could think of with the large array that I'm using. Is there a safer or recommended way?

Comment: This might be opinionated, but I'd just wrap a new type around the array and implement traits to make it behave like a 2D array, such as `Index<(usize,usize), Target=u8>`.

Comment: @E_net4 Exactly. There isn't much point in writing the data twice in different formats. The only difficult step is using modulo to change a 1 dimensional index into two; Rust only has a remainder function.

Comment: Can you read from the file into each sub-array in turn?

Comment: @Aaron3468 I can't really redo the way lookups at this point since there's a lot of code with the assumption that there is a multidimensional array.

Comment: @ChrisEmerson I've tried that, but it's way too slow at startup.

Comment: If you really need to reinterpret the 1D array as a 2D array, then it sounds like `mem::transmute` is the tool you need; you just need to be careful that it's used correctly.